# Why does graphics draw darker when using ExtGState?

Tags: pdf

I am drawing graphics objects defining ExtGState as 1
and notice that in certain scenarios the rendered graphics
are slightly darker than they should be.

You will only really notice if viewed at full magnification in Microsoft paint for example.

The PDF object in the first code block renders OK;
the same object in the second code block renders slightly darker.

What might I be doing wrong?

I'm thinking maybe it is order of operations, but nothing I change has any affect.

Also I'm thinking maybe it is something like Overprint setting or Overprint Mode,
but I don't know how to check these.

If you comment out the
/ExtGState
<<
/GS  << /ca 1   /CA 1   >>
/GS1 << /ca 0.5 /CA 0.5 >>
>>
in the 2nd code block, the rendered graphics is OK, so it definitely something to do with **ExtGState**

Code Block 1

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj
<<
    /Title (Test)
    /Author ()
    /Creator  ()
    /Producer ()
    /CreationDate (D:20231116110851+01'00')
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 3 0 R
    /PageLayout /OneColumn
    /PageMode /UseNone
    /Lang (en) 
    /ViewerPreferences << /DisplayDocTitle true /PrintScaling/None >>
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Pages
    /Count 1
    /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
    /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
    /Kids [5 0 R]
    /Resources 4 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
    /ExtGState
        <<
            /GS  << /ca 1   /CA 1   >>
            /GS1 << /ca 0.5 /CA 0.5 >>
        >>
    /ProcSet [/PDF /Text ]
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Page
    /Parent 3 0 R
    /Contents 6 0 R
>>
endobj

6 0 obj
    << /Length 7 0 R >>
stream

    %----------------------------------------------
    % start staff 1
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    90.36 589.68 466.29 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 90.36 488.7 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 G
    0.5 w
    0 G
    0 173.938 m
    60060 173.938 l
    S
    0 G
    0 182.188 m
    60060 182.188 l
    S
    0 G
    0 190.438 m
    60060 190.438 l
    S
    0 G
    0 198.688 m
    60060 198.688 l
    S
    0 G
    0 206.938 m
    60060 206.938 l
    S
    0 G
    f
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    90.36 589.68 466.29 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 90.36 488.7 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 w
    0 G
    %----------------------------------------------
    % start draw object
    0 0 0 RG
    0 0 0 rg
    /GS gs
    12.663 176.721 m
    21.712 176.721 l
    21.712 204.157 l
    12.663 204.157 l
    h
    20.209 179.727 m
    14.166 179.727 l
    14.166 201.407 l
    20.209 201.407 l
    h
    f
    0 G
    0 g
    /GS gs
    % end draw object
    %----------------------------------------------
    Q
    % end staff 1
    %----------------------------------------------


endstream
endobj

7 0 obj
8997
endobj

xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000163 00000 n
0000031883 00000 n
0000031283 00000 n
0000000374 00000 n
0000001484 00000 n
0000001746 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 45
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 2 0 R
>>
startxref
32018
%%EOF
```

Code Block 2

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj
<<
    /Title (Test)
    /Author ()
    /Creator  ()
    /Producer ()
    /CreationDate (D:20231116110851+01'00')
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 3 0 R
    /PageLayout /OneColumn
    /PageMode /UseNone
    /Lang (en) 
    /ViewerPreferences << /DisplayDocTitle true /PrintScaling/None >>
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Pages
    /Count 1
    /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
    /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
    /Kids [5 0 R]
    /Resources 4 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
    /ExtGState
        <<
            /GS  << /ca 1   /CA 1   >>
            /GS1 << /ca 0.5 /CA 0.5 >>
        >>
    /ProcSet [/PDF /Text ]
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Page
    /Parent 3 0 R
    /Contents 6 0 R
>>
endobj

6 0 obj
    << /Length 7 0 R >>
stream

    %----------------------------------------------
    % start staff 1
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    90.36 589.68 466.29 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 90.36 488.7 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 G
    0.5 w
    0 G
    0 173.938 m
    60060 173.938 l
    S
    0 G
    0 182.188 m
    60060 182.188 l
    S
    0 G
    0 190.438 m
    60060 190.438 l
    S
    0 G
    0 198.688 m
    60060 198.688 l
    S
    0 G
    0 206.938 m
    60060 206.938 l
    S
    0 G
    f
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    90.36 589.68 466.29 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 90.36 488.7 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 w
    0 G
    %----------------------------------------------
    % start draw object
    0 0 0 RG
    0 0 0 rg
    /GS gs
    12.663 176.721 m
    21.712 176.721 l
    21.712 204.157 l
    12.663 204.157 l
    h
    20.209 179.727 m
    14.166 179.727 l
    14.166 201.407 l
    20.209 201.407 l
    h
    f
    0 G
    0 g
    /GS gs
    % end draw object
    %----------------------------------------------
    Q
    % end staff 1
    %----------------------------------------------
    %----------------------------------------------
    % start staff 2
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 488.7 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -411.57 387.72 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 G
    0.5 w
    0 G
    0 173.938 m
    60060 173.938 l
    S
    0 G
    0 182.188 m
    60060 182.188 l
    S
    0 G
    0 190.438 m
    60060 190.438 l
    S
    0 G
    0 198.688 m
    60060 198.688 l
    S
    0 G
    0 206.938 m
    60060 206.938 l
    S
    0 G
    f
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 488.7 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -411.57 387.72 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 w
    0 G
    Q
    % end staff 2   
    %----------------------------------------------

endstream
endobj

7 0 obj
8997
endobj

xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000163 00000 n
0000031883 00000 n
0000031283 00000 n
0000000374 00000 n
0000001484 00000 n
0000001746 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 45
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 2 0 R
>>
startxref
32018
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not absoloutly clear where you think the difference is on a zoom in since renders are rarely the same unless same objects set to same colouring.

Your "Minimum" supplied example files need adjustments to run as have many missed directions in the trailer but when those are set the 2 files appear similar.

[image]

A problem with screen render as you can see is that lines are not vectors when seen as raster so some will look "greyer" than others

Second set on left and first set on right both are black and white or tones due to screen anti-alias.
[image]

Mitigation can be difficult

- Lines need to be at least 1 point minimum wide (no less than 1.3 mm at scale)
- Lines should be spaced evenly in multiple units of 1.3 points apart (more difficult to determine that spacing)
- Reprex of vectors as raster's need visual testing where critical such as bar codes where there should be no anti-alias allowed
  [image]
- A well crafted bitmap can often outperform a sloppy vector in a PDF
  [image][image]

**One issue with graphics state is it will be constantly changing OR resetting to defaults, or over-rides. so you need to measure at each step or consider why it is not changed from last**.

Comment: Thanks @KJ ----- Could you instruct me how to "adjust trailer" so if I can see that both files produce same results. -----  this [link](https://www.imagevenue.com/ME175ITH) shows difference in renderings, the left-most images are WITHOUT ExtGState (so I assume correct), the middle images are from 1st  PDF code block, and are same as left-most images, and right-most images are from 2nd PDF code block and are darker

Comment: Thanks again @KJ ----- The ExtGStateA opens and closes nicely; ExtGState2 closes with an Adobe Dialog "Do you want to save changes to 'ExtGState2.pdf' before closing?"  so must still be a Trailer error?

Comment: The problem for me is **not** the anti-aliasing, but the fact that **using** ExtGState in **some** instances produce **different** renderings (ie my 2nd ExtGState file produces darker results than my1st ExtGState file) ----- I'm just trying to understand the WHY?

Comment: I'm only viewing the rendered page at 100% magnification in Adobe ----- If the rendered page (using ExtGState) is **completely** filled with objects, it just looks too dark and messy compared with same page without ExtGState ----- I only looked at it magnified to see WHY the difference. ----- I'm sure I'm just using it wrong some how. ----- For me same Adobe Viewer, same File, same screen, same 100% viewing magnification, only difference is using ExtGState or not ----- but DIFFERENT output.

Comment: OK this is strange ----- If I look at your png file in comment directly above, I see what you say, 2 identical solid black rectangles ----- but if I myself open **your** ExtGStateA.pdf and ExtGStateB2.pdf files (100% magnification), take a Snapshot [link](https://www.imagevenue.com/ME175K7X) of each, I get **exactly** same image as in comment 1 that you replied "Hmm interesting" which shows a **distinct** difference between the 2 files

Comment: But surely anti-alias **is** needed for all objects that are not comprised of lines that are not at 0 and 90 degrees, and all objects that are constructed of bezier curves as most of mine are

Comment: All my objects are vector graphics ----- If I didn't need to use ExtGstate, I wound not, but I need it when I need to render certain objects at some degree of transparency ----- I am going to delve into other ExtGState settings such as BlendMode (BM),  Overprint (OP), OverPrintMode (OPM), etc  ----- need a PhD in I don't know what, to understand the 1,300 page PDF Reference :)

Comment: So when I close either of the 2 "minimal" files I created here for demonstration, I get the "Do you want to save changes to 'ExtGState2.pdf' Dialog from Adobe because as @KJ notes, I have an incorrect Trailer address ----- I always answer NO to this question so that I keep my underlying code **readable** ----- Just to see what happens, I answered YES and voila, the output of the 2nd file is **identical** to the first ----- this confirms to me I am doing something wrong in my graphics calls (or at least not quite right) and Adobe Acrobat  is able to correct it ----- hope I can find my error

Comment: Is it possible to make the unreadable code generated by Acrobat readable in any way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "raise need for add to answer" ----- I will copy all your answers to text file and I will save all your links ----- Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: comment by @ K J ->"focus on just the intended part. One issue with graphics state is it will be constantly changing OR resetting to defaults, or over-rides. so you need to measure at each step or consider why it is not changed from last." ----- is my problem for sure